# Loop through all but four sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have 15 sheets, of which I need to loop through all but four sheets named graphs, print, summary and print.

My code only excludes the first sheet and not the other three.

```
Dim Current As Worksheet

For Each Current In Worksheets 

 If Current.Name <> "Summary" And Current.Name <> "Model" And Current.Name <> "Print" And Current.Name <> "Graphs" Then

MsgBox Current.Name

Next

End Sub
```

I am looking to be able to exclude the four sheets in the output. TIA

Comment: You're missing an `End If` in your question. That said, no repro. Use of `And` here is correct. Do you by chance have `Or` in your actual code?

Comment: The original code is quite long, which I had truncated. The missing 'End If' is a typo. Thanks for pointing out and apologies for that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Sub Sheets_Walk()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets

        If s_in_A1(ws.Name, a1_Names) = False Then

            MsgBox ws.Name

        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function s_in_A1( _
        s As String, _
        a1 As Variant) _
        As Boolean

    Dim lCol As Long

    For lCol = LBound(a1) To UBound(a1)

        If a1(lCol) = s Then

            s_in_A1 = True

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function a1_Names() _
        As Variant

    a1_Names = Array("Summary", "Model", "Print", "Graphs")

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub whatever()
    Dim Current As Worksheet, c As String

    For Each Current In Worksheets
        c = Current.Name
        If c <> "Summary" And c <> "Model" And c <> "Print" And c <> "Graphs" Then
            MsgBox c
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If `c = Current.Name`, is this logically any different from OP?

Comment: How is this any different from the OP's code (except for the missing `End If` indicated by BigBen)?

Comment: It's a complete, testable example for one, and the End If problem with OP's code is corrected, and finally, it's easier to read, particularly as a code example here.

Comment: @Steve That still doesn't make it _logically_ different from the OP's code. The missing `End If` is most likely a typo because otherwise, the code wouldn't compile. Fixing that would make the code in the question actually work, not produce the described behavior. IMO, when a question is missing an MCVE, we VTC using that reason until the OP provides one instead of posting an answer with basically the same code. _That_ was the point of my comment (not whether or not the code is easier to read). I could be wrong after all and I didn't even downvote the answer. I'm just saying my opinion :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed And a reasonable opinion it is, Ahmed. I simply prefer the answer from Gary's Student as a better "for the record" answer to the problem.